# Flutter FCM shows empty notification when no notification data is sent and when app is in bg

Tags: flutter, push-notification, google-cloud-functions, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm sending FCM notification from my cloud functions to my flutter app.

I don't want the FCM system to handle notification display when the app is in background or terminated. Hence, I'm sending the data to show in notification in the `data` key instead of the `notification` key.

Cloud Functions:

```
await admin.messaging().sendMulticast({
  tokens: userFCMTokens,
  data: {
    title: "Notification title to display",
    body: "Notification body to display",
  },
  android: {
    notification: {
      channelId: "some_channel_id",
    },
  },
});
```

On the client side (i.e. Flutter app) I'm receiving/handling the FCM messages and displaying them with the [awesome_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications) plugin.

Flutter:

```dart
AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
  content: NotificationContent(
    id: message.hashCode,
    channelKey: message.notification?.android?.channelId,
    title: message.data['title'],
    body: message.data['body'],
    bigPicture: message.data['imageUrl'],
    wakeUpScreen: true,
    notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.BigPicture,
  ),
  actionButtons: (message.data['actions'] as List<Map>?)
      ?.map(
        (e) => NotificationActionButton(
          key: e['key'],
          label: e['label'],
        ),
      )
      .toList(),
);
```

This setup works properly when the app is in foreground but when in background or terminated it shows 2 notification. One proper and one totally empty notification.

[image]

I don't want the FCM SDK system to handle the notification hence I'm using `data` instead of `notification` but then this problem arises.

Comment: Hi, Where you able to fix it? please add it as an answer if you could solve it, I'm in the same situation.

Comment: @user2682025 Hi, unfortunately I have not been able to solve it yet. So I'm using a different approach with lots of conditional checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating reproducible code sample, I got to know that even though I was not adding `notification` directly, I was adding it in `android`. And that was creating the empty notification as the `message.notification` in dart was not empty/null due to it.

Not working code

```js
await getMessaging().send({
  token: "{{userFCMToken}}",
  data: {
    title: "Hello, World",
    body: "This is a notification",
  },
  android: {
    notification: {
      channelId: "general_notifications",
      clickAction: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
    },
  },
  apns: {
    payload: {
      aps: {
        mutableContent: true,
        contentAvailable: true,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

When I set my server notification code without the `notification` field in `android` is is now working fine.

Working code

```js
await getMessaging().send({
  token: "{{userFCMToken}}",
  data: {
    title: "Hello, World",
    body: "This is a notification",
  },
  android: {},
  apns: {
    payload: {
      aps: {
        mutableContent: true,
        contentAvailable: true,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

---

For more information on how to reproduce or test this check out this [comment](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/10918#issuecomment-1538842331)